# Fetch data in every 5 second in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How can I run a query to fetch data every 5 second in codieginiter?

My query is:

```
    $this->db->order_by('added_on', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit('50');
    if($from_date == '' && $to_date == '')
        $where = ('(status = "'.pending.'" or status = "'.error.'")');
    else
        $where = "DATE_FORMAT(added_on,'%Y-%m-%d') >='".$from_date."'AND DATE_FORMAT(added_on,'%Y-%m-%d')<='".$to_date."' AND (status='error' OR status='pending')";
    $query = $this->db->get_where('cp_purchase_transaction_history',$where);
    //echo $this->db->last_query();die;
```

Comment: You need to add more brief regarding your problem is it related to build a query for 5 seconds delay or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

please check your condition as follows

```
added_on >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 SECOND)
```

Answer (score 0):

## If you wish the user get updated data every 5 seconds:

then you should send ajax from browser every 5 seconds.

See

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

## If you wish to backup the newest data every 5 seconds in the server:

What you need is cronjob. Set a cronjob to execute the php every 5 seconds.

If your OS is Ubuntu, see

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html

Wish they help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cronjob implementing this type of functionality

other wise use setinterval like this :

```
setInterval(function()
{ 
    $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"myurl.html",
      datatype:"html",
      success:function(data)
      {
          //do something with response data
      }
    });
}, 10000);//time in milliseconds
```